# How to use SF Mono in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have encountered some issues for setting up SF Mono font in VS Code.

### Method 1

Add the following configuration in `settings.json`

```
"editor.fontFamily": "SF Mono"
```

[image]

The font seems to be bold, and changing `"editor.fontWeight"` to `100` doesn't help.

### Method 2

```
"editor.fontFamily": "SFMono-Regular"
```

[image]

The texts have regular font weights now, but the comment is still bold.

### Method 3

Try to configure the comment text separately.

```
"editor.fontFamily": "SFMono-Regular",
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
      {
        "scope": "comment",
        "settings": {
            "fontStyle": "normal"
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

[image]

It seems configuring comment texts to `normal` gives them regular font weight.

My question is how to have regular SF Mono weights while having italic comments?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To use SF Mono in VS Code:

1. Remove your local version of SF Mono if it appears in Font Book.
2. Download the most recent version of SF Mono from Apple here: https://developer.apple.com/fonts/
3. In VS Code's settings set `SF Mono` as your preferred font. My config is `SF Mono, Menlo, Monaco, 'Courier New', monospace`
4. Restart VS Code

SF Mono should display properly, with the correct weight italics.